# Indexing only single object field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine i have some document that has relations to other type of document, say, *building* that is related to *regions*:

```
building:
  country: region
  city: region
  nearbyParks: [region]
  closestNuclearHideout: region
```

I need to be able to perform a search by any region that is related to building, so i'm converting this structure to:

```
building:
  countryId: <uuid>
  cityId: <uuid>
  nearbyParkIds: [<uuid>]
  closestNuclearHideoutId: <uuid>
  regions: [region]
```

However, by this very moment i need to perform searches only by related region id, and would love to forbid ElasticSearch to index every `regions.*` field (except for `regions.id`) to keep things clean. Is this possible using current mapping API? I would love to keep my elastic documents as small as possible and also keep them in sync with backend output, so adding `regionIds` uuid array field is an option, but an unwanted one.

Comment: If you don't need the info about regions, you can store only region id in ElasticSearch and retrieve the rest of the info from your other storage (database or whatever).

Comment: Can you share some more info, i.e. what client technology are you using? How are you creating your index and mapping types?

Comment: @Val i'm using official java client with standard zero-downtime aliasing concept, mappings are created with index.

Comment: @Ashalynd yes, that's the regionIds field solution. I'm trying to avoid it so backend (database) and elastic output will be identical for client.

Comment: Then can you show how you're creating your index and the mapping you're using?

Comment: @Val **pickypg** already pinpointed the ideal solution, so i won't go in detail, but this is simple nested object with only id field specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can turn off `dynamic` mappings for a given field. In the mappings, you can therefore define the fields you *do* want to map, while effectively disabling the rest for search.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "type": {
      "properties": {
        "regions": {
          "type": "object",
          "dynamic": false,
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "doc_values" : true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, imagining that you indexed this document:

```
{
  "regions" : [
    {
      "id" : "xyzabc",
      "field1" : "ignored",
      "field2" : "ignored"
    },
    {
      "id" : "abcdef",
      "field1" : "ignored",
      "field2" : "ignored",
      "field3" : "ignored"
    }
  ]
}
```

The non-`id` fields would be ignored by the mapping and they would therefore not be searchable (without a script), but you *would* get them back as `_source` results in your hits.

Comment: Fantastic, i can't imagine how did i miss this one. Lots of thanks!